# ida jumping to address I can't see in driver

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows, binary-analysis, x86-64

When I open this driver in IDA i can't seem to see the instructions that this `jmp` at `0x1400DC46D` jumps to.  [image]

I've tried to undefine bytes and re-analyze the function but it then ends up will garbage. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the dumb question. A little bit of research could've solved this. Turns out undefining the E8 byte will solve your problem.